# Click on two buttons at the same time, if one covers the other one

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

What I want to do is just as the tiltle says. The reason is , I am not able to custome the view of the below button, so I plan to put another button on this button which can be customed by myself. And when I touch the upper one, the event of the belown one will be triggered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's say there are two UIButtons A & B.

In the touch event (touchupinside) of A add the following code:

```
[buttonObjectB sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

This will trigger second button's touch event as you desire.